# How can I use django mezzanine?

Tags: django, mezzanine, django-apps

I am planning to build using Django a website where users can ask to be interviewed and I post it in the website, I looked over the internet, and I saw that Mezzanine might be a good framework because my website will be like a blog.

However I may add new features that are not related to a blog.

So my question is should I create a new django project and add mezzanine as an app or create directly a mezzanine project ? Or is there another solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use Mezzanine, the easiest and cleanest way to do so is to start directly with a Mezzanine project following the [installation docs](https://mezzanine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#installation).

Starting with a generic django project and tacking on Mezzanine is possible but not straightforward. Part of the reason is that Mezzanine is not just a single app but a collection of apps that need to be properly configured in your global settings. The `mezzanine-project` command preconfigures all this painlessly but your project is still "pure" django and you can add whatever additional functionality you need.